# What's the best way to restrict access to documents in aws s3 to protect access users from other tenants accessing it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, multi-tenant, claims-based-identity

The application allows users to "generate reports" which are stored in S3. These reports can be downloaded by users belonging to the same tenant. What is the best way to ensure users of one tenant cannot access reports from another tenant at all?

I can add "tenant_id" as a custom attribute in the Cognito user pool and also an object tag to files in s3 bucket prefixed with tenant_id as well.

I was wondering if I could just compare those in a lambda function to ensure that the object being accessed has the same tenant_id tag as is in the token from the Cognito pool.

As I read online, It usually says that for "access to AWS resources like S3", we need an identity pool and policy generated on the fly but do I really (which I think is called claims based identity) ? Can it not be done just one the basis of the custom attribute in the pool which will be available in the JWT token used to access the file. Why should I exactly need an identity pool here then?

Would be great to see some examples if it is possible to do it this way

Comment: How do the users download these reports?

Comment: Through the web application using Download button

Comment: In that case, I would recommend granting the web application access to the bucket, and letting it control which documents can be downloaded for which users.

Comment: @kdgregory Wouldn't it add an additional level of security if we restricted that at s3 level as well?

Comment: To provide additional security, you would need for the client to control the credentials used to access and/or decrypt their files.